# Tailwind ver3.2.4: @apply styles don't applied at all

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I started learning Tailwind framework by following the "From Zero to Production" series on thier official youtube channel but I'm stacking in @apply which it doesn't work at all and Vscode keep showing me a warning "Unknown at rule @apply".
I've read the docs on thier site and everything is ok and nothing different.

here are the configurations and my code :

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tailwind",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.20",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "vite": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

style.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .btn {
    @apply inline-block px-5 py-3 rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-offset-2 uppercase tracking-wider font-semibold text-sm sm:text-base;
  }
  .btn-primary {
    @apply bg-indigo-500 text-white hover:bg-indigo-400 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-opacity-50 active:bg-indigo-600;
  }
  .btn-secondary {
    @apply bg-gray-300 text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:ring-gray-300 focus:ring-opacity-50 active:bg-gray-400;
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="styleshee" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body class="bg-gray-600">
    <div class="bg-gray-100 grid lg:grid-cols-2">
        <div class="p-8 py-12 max-w-md mx-auto sm:max-w-xl lg:max-w-full">
            <h3 class="">Workation</h3>
            <img src="./coffee-bg10.jpg"
            class="mt-6 rounded-lg shadow-xl lg:hidden" alt="just an img"/>
            <h1 class="mt-6 text-2xl font-bold text-gray-900 sm:mt-8 lg:text-4xl">You can work from anywhere.<br>  <span class="text-indigo-500">Take advantage of it.</span></h1>
            <p class="mt-2 text-gray-600">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. ccusamus repudiandae sapiente. Repepsam laudantium fugiat at unde. Facere, voluptates quidem!</p>
            <div class="mt-6">
              <a href="#" class="inline-block bg-indigo-500 hover:bg-indigo-700 active:translate-y-0.5 transform transition focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-700 text-white text-sm uppercase font-semibold tracking-wider px-5 py-3 rounded-lg shadow-lg">Book your Escape</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn-primary">or here</a>
            </div>
        </div>
          <div class="hidden lg:block relative">
              <img src="./coffee-bg10.jpg"
            class="absolute inset-0 w-full h-full object-cover object-center" alt="just an img"/>
          </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is just a warning right, your project still complies and css is applied?

Comment: @Yilmaz yeah it's working correctly. my problem is in the styles, if I write Tailwind classes between HTML tags it works like what I did in the img and h3 but class="btn-primary" nothing of its styles appear because it's defined using "@apply" and I don't know why though it should work normally

Comment: Can you add this extension `Tailwind CSS IntelliSense`. you might need to restart the vscode

Comment: @Yilmaz tried but nothing changed the problem still exist.

Comment: can u set  ` "css.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore" ` in settings.json

Comment: @Yilmaz didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Your css file needs to go through a compilation process using the command `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/style.css -o ./dist/style.css`. It doesn't look like you're doing it.

Also, when you install tailwind as a dependency in an npm project, you don't need to import the tailwind cdn with `<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>`, because all your styles must be generated on your machine.